# Why does the result of an expression depend on where the expression is placed?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char, integer-arithmetic

I am currently working on a more complex program, and I came across a very weird syntax error best demonstrated with the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char c = 1 + '0';
        std::cout << 1 + '0' << std::endl;
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
        std::cout << '0' + 1 << std::endl;
        return 1;
}
```

This example produces the following output:

```
$ ./program
49
1
49
```

What appears to be happening here is that when the conversion from a single digit integer expression to a character happens outside a stream statement, it succeeds, but when it happens inside such a statement, it produces a garbage answer.

I tried to find someone else asking something similar on Google, but I can't find anything relevant.

I am using g++ `(Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64, but the issue occurs in clang `version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)` as well, which rules out a compiler bug.

Comment: With `auto i = 1 + '0'; std::cout << i << std::endl;`. You will get `49` too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of a `int + char` is an `int`.  So when you do

```
char c = 1 + '0';
```

You actually get

```
char c = 49;
```

And now `c` has the value of `49`.  When yo go to print that though, `cout`'s `operator <<` is overloaded to take a `char` and instead of displaying `49` it will display the character that `49` represents.

When you do

```
std::cout << 1 + '0' << std::endl;
```

Since `1 + '0'` is an `int` you get the `int` overload of `operator <<` which just outputs the integer 49.

---

It should be noted that anything smaller than an `int` will be promoted to an `int` when doing arithmetic operations.  That means that, `char + char`, `short + short`, `char + short`, ..., will all be an `int` so even doing something like

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(1) + '0' << std::endl;
```

Will still give you a integer output.  You have to cast the result back to a `char` to get a `char` like

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(1 + '0') << std::endl;
```

Comment: When I change the first cout statement to `std::cout << static_cast<char>(1) + '0' << std::endl;` the output remains unchanged, despite the fact it is now a char + char = char statement, so it should use the overload of `operator<<` for a char. Why?

Comment: @john01dav Change it to `static_cast<char>(1 + '0')`.

Comment: @john01dav Anything that is smaller than an `int` is promoted to an `int` when doing operations to it.  So `char + char`, `short + short`, `char + short`, ... will all be an `int`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! Although can I recommend that as a good addition to the answer for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

> but when it happens inside such a statement, it produces a garbage
>   answer.

No.

```
char c = 1 + '0';
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

In this case the rvalue `int` is implicitly converted to `char`. Then the `char` overload is used with `std::cout`, resulting in '1' as ASCII.

---

```
std::cout << 1 + '0' << std::endl;
```

In this case you're printing out the integer right away, so the integer overload is picked, this prints the numeric value of the '1' which is 49.